# filtering through an array of JSON objects by UI

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I want to display a list of Dogs with a search bar above which when typed in will only display the dogs which meet the criteria.

I previously had the array stored in state and everything was working fine. However now, looking forward once up and running I will have thousands of entries inside of the array and it will get too messy. So I have decided that I wish to store all of my objects in JSON format as it will be a lot easier to manage I believe.

I'm stuck, I have tried to integrate the .json file into the old format but I am not getting any data come up and when I type in the searchbar i get an error message.

here is my json:

```
[
 {
  "id": 3,
  "title": "Sir",
  "content":"My name is Sir Jeffrey"
 },
 {
  "id": 4,
  "title": "Prince",
  "content": "My name is Prince Gareth"
 },
 {
  "id": 5,
  "title": "Princess",
  "content": "My name is Princess Roy Roy"
},
{
 "id": 6,
 "title": "King",
 "content": "My name is King George"
}
```

]

My App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import DogsList from './components/dogslist.js';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <DogsList/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My List function:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Dog from './listlayouts.js';



 function DogList(postDetail){
  let dogs = postDetail.filteredDogs.map((dog, i) => {
    return <Dog key={postDetail.id} Name={postDetail.title} Content= 
   {postDetail.content}/>
   })
  return(
  <div>
    {dogs}
  </div>
  )
 };

 export default DogList;
```

List Layout:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

function Dog(postDetail){
  return(
    <div>
    <p>Name: {postDetail.title}</p>
    <p>Content: {postDetail.content}</p>
    </div>
  )
 }

export default Dog;
```

Search box function:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

function DogSearchBox(postDetail){
  return (
    <div>
     <input onChange={postDetail.handleInput} type ='text'/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DogSearchBox;
```

And the Doglist component which should render with a empty searchbar above the list of all dogs and then the list should change once the User types in the searchbar.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DogList from './listfunctions.js';
import DogSearchBox from './searchboxfunctions.js';
import postData from './dogs.json';


class DogsList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dogs: [
        <div>
          {postData.map((postDetail, index) => {
            return(
              <div>
               <h2>{postDetail.title}</h2>
               <p>{postDetail.content}</p>
              </div>
            )
          })}

         </div>
      ],
      searchDog:''
    }
  }

  handleInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({searchDog: e.target.value})
  }

  render() {

    let filteredDogs = this.state.dogs.filter(dog => 
    Object.values(dog).some(val => 
    val.toString().toLowerCase().includes
    (this.state.searchDog.toLowerCase())))

    return (
     <div>
      <header>
      <h1>Dogs</h1>
      </header>
      <div>
      <DogSearchBox handleInput = {this.handleInput}/>
      <DogList filteredDogs = {filteredDogs}/>
     </div>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DogsList;
```

I am still new to it all but I have a feeling i will no longer need all of these components. I am more then happy to simplify it as much as possible. Just as long as it works as intended.

Comment: Hello when you are mapping your json data in your `DogList` function what is the value of the postDetail can you console log that value? Also what is the error message you get when you want to search?

Comment: "hen I type in the searchbar i get an error message. "<---what error do you get ?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/corey/Desktop/said1/src/components/dogslist.js:34
  31 | 
  32 |  render() {
  33 | 
> 34 |    let filteredDogs = this.state.dogs.filter(dog => Object.values(dog).some(
     | ^  35 |      val => val.toString().toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchDog.toLowerCase())))
  36 | 
  37 |    return (

Comment: you're passing different props than what you're trying to use. `<Dog Name={postDetail.title}` but in `Dog` you are trying to use the key `title` rather than `Name`. Maybe what you want to do is  `<Dog postDetail={postDetail}`

Comment: why is there jsx in your state? Inside `DogsList` you're defining state with jsx.

Comment: thanks John, like I said, I am a beginner and i had it all working using a state array. So I have tried to remove the state array and incorporate the json into it. I have no doubt there will be things wrong.

Comment: dont do that. its not how you should be rendering elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're issue is you are defining JSX elements inside your state. Then you try to convert it to a string.

```
class DogsList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dogs: [
        <div>
  // -----^--------------
          {postData.map((postDetail, index) => {
            return(
              <div>
               <h2>{postDetail.title}</h2>
               <p>{postDetail.content}</p>
              </div>
            )
          })}

         </div>
  // -------^--------------
      ],
      searchDog:''
    }
  }
```

instead you should just store data in state, create the elements during render

```
class DogsList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dogs: [...postData],
      searchDog:''
    }
  }
  render() {
    const filteredDogs = ...
    return <div>
      <DogList dogs={filteredDogs} />
    </div>
  }
}
```

then fix the issue where you're passing the wrong props to the dog component

```
function DogList({dogs){
  let elems = dogs.map((dog, i) => {
    return <Dog key={dog.id} {...dog} />
  })

  return(
    <div>
      {elems}
    </div>
  )
};
```

Comment: thanks John however I previously did have the data stored in state, but because I will end up wanting to have thousands of objects I think the array will just get too long and messy. (there will be many more props and images for each object). So I want to store the data as JSON as I think it will keep my code neater.

Comment: Then implement pagination, or infinite load. and probably a state management system like redux

Comment: This is not gonna fix the issue as there are incorrect props passed in the child components.

Comment: @Clarity i know, already called that out in the comments before your answer :) but the compilation error is this. I was letting your answer call out that portion so you'd get upvotes for that part. but sure i can add the rest

Comment: ah ok, got it :)

Comment: @Georg you aren't storing JSON in your state. Thats what im trying to point out lol

Comment: Ok John, Maybe I should just try starting fresh. Its just I had it all working fine when I was storing the array in state. I was hoping it wouldn't be hard to change it and store it in json instead. But have it work the same.

Comment: an array is json. What do you mean by store it as json?

Comment: As in a seperate json file. So that the array of objects is a seperate file. Previously I had the array in the state of DogsList, but I replaced it with this:                                <div>
          {postData.map((postDetail, index) => {
            return(
              <div>
               <h2>{postDetail.title}</h2>
               <p>{postDetail.content}</p>
              </div>
            )
          })}

         </div>

Comment: Yea, `<div>` is translated to `React.createElement('div'...` so when you try to `filter` on the React Element its not going to have a `toString` method and your code crashes. Furthermore you shouldn't be storing that in state. [**you could do something like this**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-ejuyl) if you want to move the data to another file. I did a js file just because of the loader config in the codesandbox. you could keep a `.json` extension as long as you have the appropriate loader :)

Comment: This is what I wanted John, I should be able to carry on from this. How can I mark that as an answer or give you an up vote ? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Hey @Georg glad that helped! I see you already marked it as accepted, thanks for that :) Feel free to ask more questions if you have them and I'll try and help if able :)

Comment: @Georg yep what's up?

Comment: So I want to be able to add social icons to each list item depending on if or not they have a Facebook page. At the moment I’ve got the URL for the Facebook page stored in the items json. And then in list layouts I have placed an <a/> tag which points to the postDetail.facebook. And it wraps <Fbook/> which is my social icon. It all works great except for the fact it places the icon in every list item. I only want it to place the icon on the list items which actually have a URL stored in the json. If it doesn’t make sense I’ll make a new question when I have a bit more time later. Cheers

Comment: Well you should just conditionally render it. `{hasFacebookUrl ? <Fbook /> : null }`

Comment: Ok so in my list layouts. Instead of using postDetail.Facebook. I’ll give it a go thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: @John Ruddell that worked absolutely perfect. Geezus that was so simple for you. hope I get that good one day. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In your list component you're passing incorrect props to the `Dog` component, try changing it to:

```
function DogList(filteredDogs){
  let dogs = filteredDogs.map((dog) => {
    return <Dog key={dog.id} dog={dog} />
   })
  return(
     <div>
      {dogs}
     </div>
     )
  };
```

and then in the layout component you can access the props as:

```
function Dog(dog){
  return(
    <div>
    <p>Name: {dog.title}</p>
    <p>Content: {dog.content}</p>
    </div>
  )
 }
```

EDIT: Also it seems like you're not passing correct data already in your main component. Change it to this by removing the unnecessary `dogs` state and passing post data directly to filter:

```
class DogsList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       searchDog:''
    }
  }

  handleInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({searchDog: e.target.value})
  }

  render() {

    let filteredDogs = postData.filter(dog => 
    Object.values(dog).some(val => 
    val.toString().toLowerCase().includes
    (this.state.searchDog.toLowerCase())))

    return (
     <div>
      <header>
      <h1>Dogs</h1>
      </header>
      <div>
      <DogSearchBox handleInput = {this.handleInput}/>
      <DogList filteredDogs = {filteredDogs}/>
     </div>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DogsList;
```

Comment: thanks clarity, I am now getting this error.                                                               
    filteredDogs.map is not a function                                                                       
    6 | function DogList(filteredDogs){
>  7 |   let dogs = filteredDogs.map((dog) => {
   8 |     return <Dog key={dog.id} dog={dog} />
   9 |    })
  10 |   return(

Comment: can you console.log(filteredDogs) before let dogs = filteredDogs.map((dog) => { and see what it shows?